# Airflow taskgroup has status failed while all tasks in group have status success

Tags: python, airflow

I have question regarding taskgroups in Airflow. My DAG contains two taskgroups that each contain a number of python operators. When I run my DAG all python operators are executed successfully and the DAG gets marked as success as well. However, when I look at the grid view in the UI it seems that my two taskgroups have status failed. Anyone knows what causes these taskgroups to 'fail'?

*Note: in the screenshot below I selected the first taskgroup. The second red box is the second taskgroup that also has status failed.*

[image]

Comment: can you provide some info (how do you deploy your airflow server, which version are you using, ...), and provide some code in order to reproduce the problem and help you to solve it?

Comment: More context is needed for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid view was introduced in Airflow 2.3 and it has some UI issues in consecutive releases.

I recommend you upgrade first to the latest version of Airflow (2.4.3) and if the issue persists, please provide more context to reproduce it.